# Copy files, and skip the ones in use

Tags: windows, powershell, get-childitem

I am attempting to make a PowerShell script to run every night, to copy over PDF files from C:\share1 to C:\share2 and write to the event log.

My current file copy script bit looks like this:

```
Try
{
    get-childitem -Path C:\Share1 | ForEach-Object { Copy-Item $_.FullName C:\share2 -verbose } 
    #Writes to event log as success.

}
Catch
    #Logs the event as failed
}
```

The issue I run into here is that the files beeing copied/replaced are in use.
When a file is in use the script stops copying on that said file with a error:

```
PS>TerminatingError(Copy-Item): "The process cannot access the file 'C:/share2/1.pdf' because it is being used by another process."
```

I would like to at least modify my script so it continues to copy the remaining files.

If i for example had 100 files and the 3rd one was in use, the entire transfer stops.

How can I modify my script to continue on remaining items?

Comment: What's the _entire_ error that you get returned when this issue occurs? You can  `catch` specific error types.

Comment: It starts to copy the files, and stops on the one that is in use by another machine, then goes to "Transcript stopped" with the "PS terminatingError" mentioned above as the content of the transcript output file.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the common `-ErrorAction` paramter with set to `SilentlyContinue`:

```
get-childitem -Path C:\Share1 | ForEach-Object { Copy-Item $_.FullName C:\share2 -verbose -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue }
```

**Note:** You *don't* need the `Foreach-Object` cmdlet here:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Share1 | Copy-Item C:\share2 -verbose -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

**Note 2:** As gvee mentioned, this will ignore all errors. Another option would be to use handle.exe from the sysinternals suite to check whether there is an open handle.

Comment: Whilst this will work - it will ignore **all** errors, not just file in use ones

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much for your reply!
If i don't use the ForEach-Object, i wont get the verbose output (atleast in console).

However it still stops even when ErrorAction is set to Silently continue.
Same terminating error... Any other tips?